# Render chart with data from Views PHP custom field

Tags: 7, views, nodes, charts

How to render a Column Chart using data from Views PHP custom field (**BAR Number (PHP custom)** in the screenshot below)?

[image]

I am trying to achieve a Column Chart; with each bar in the chart being **distinct count number of "bar number".**

1. I have tried using aggregation (with [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module chart add-on enabled), but does not give option to aggregate/count on PHP custom fields.
2. have tried [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module, but again it does not consider PHP Views custom fields for Grouping.

Just for more information on what I am trying to achieve, please refer below Requirement screenshot!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A work around for issue `1.` & `2.` Add Bar number as a field to each study node. Then add field to view, and aggregate.

How exactly is the Bar Number being calculated? You could use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to calculate this value when node is saved and save the calc number to your Bar number field. If there is no calculation, then ignore this part.

Use [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to not allow certain roles to change the value of this field, if needed.

---

Add a new field called Bar Number (machine name: field_bar_number) to your study content type.

You can create a custom module.

**mymodule.info**

```
name = My Module
description = Makes calculation for Bar Number field in Study content type.
package = Custom
version = 7.x-1.0
core = 7.x
```

**mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements of hook_node_presave
 */
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type =='study') {
    // calculates bar number
    $node->field_bar_number = $node->some_field - $node->other_field;                          
  }
}
```

Use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and set title = title, and save again all your 500 nodes. As your custom module makes the calculation and sets the bar number before the node is saved. [VBO Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu8KkdjPucM).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Bar number is calculated in the view, in PHP custom date_diff => "Collection_date - Date_of_Onset" and some calculations to calculate bar number.    And, There are around 500 study node records.

Comment: @Maddy see my updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, shall try out this and will get back to you with the results. cheers